# VBA PowerPoint Shapes in Heap

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Are the shapes in PowerPoint are stored in Heap, when we create a shape/shapes in PowerPoint slide or when we create a shape/shapes through VBA code?

Thanks and Regards,
Balu.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by Heap.  In case it helps, PPT keeps slides and shapes in collections:  the Presentaiton object's .Slides collection and each Slide's .Shapes collection. You can access items in a collection by name or index.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply. As you know, heap is a large memory for objects and structures. Just in curiousity, to know, where the shape structure is stored in memory, to learn the concept of data structures.

Comment: From the point of view of VBA/other languages and the PowerPoint object model, shapes and slides are stored in collections. How Microsoft implements collections internally ...? Not documented, as far as I know.